# How can I add a credential to a pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I go to the credentials page of our jenkins server, I can view and update credentials but I don't see any way to add a new credential.

As my job is a pipeline job, there is no `Bindings` section in the job config.

The only way I can figure out how to add a credential is by going to a non-pipeline job, checking `Use secret text(s) or file(s)` under that job's `Bindings`, using that UI to add a credential, and then cancelling my changes.

This seems unwieldy as it requires me to edit a completely unrelated job just to add a credential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, the UX is a bit odd. i have to click Credentials, and then under that in the left nav there is a link to "System", and after i click that i can see "Global credentials (unrestricted)", and when i click that, finally i can see an "Add Credentials" link in the left nav.

[this guide](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) seems basically correct, but is missing the "System" step that is necessary for me.

for me the path ends up being: /credentials/store/system/domain/_/newCredentials